# retrieve data after search :: laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have problem when i want to retrieve my data

first i get data from view and after send it to controller like this :

view :

```
            {{ Form::open() }}
                {{ Form::label('Title : ') }}
                {{ Form::text('Search') }}
                {{ Form::submit('Search') }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

route :

```
Route::get('search', function () {
    return view('search');
});

Route::post('search', 'SearchController@Search');
```

controller :

```
public function Search () {

    $SearchText = Input::get('Search');

    return Posts::where('Title', 'LIKE', '%'.$SearchText.'%')->get();

}
```

now i want to return th columns of table that i searched.

i try " Posts->ID , Posts->Description " but it is wrong......

Comment: Do you want to search by `id` and `description` as well?

Comment: @TheAlpha no , i want to return the id and description of the record that i search it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will give you a group of posts

```
Posts::where('Title', 'LIKE', '%'.$SearchText.'%')->get();
```

So to get the `id` and the `description`,
you can do this in your blade template:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->id }} <br>
    {{ $post->description }}
@endforeach
```

In you `PHP` code, you can do:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {

  $postId = $post->id;
  $postDescription = $post->description;

}
```